# Is it possible publishing a Python Add-in in a web service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, web-service, python-addin

I'm trying to make a multiuser web service for editing an ArcSDE geodatabase.
I wanted to know if I can to add my python add-in in Arcgis Server? And if the answer is yes, how can I publish it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Python Add-Ins are only usable in the desktop ArcGIS applications (ArcMap, ArcCatalog, etc.).